# Fate of unsupported Lightning features?

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, fieldsets, apex-managed-sharing, apex-sharing

Has Salesforce has said anything (officially or unofficially) about whether or not Lightning will support the below features that currently you have to switch back to Classic to manage? I have not been able to find an answer anywhere, other than that they are on the ["Point-and-Click Customization: What’s Different or Not Available in Lightning Experience"](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_gaps_limitations_ui_customization.htm&type=5) list.

- Field Sets
- Apex Sharing Rules
- Apex Sharing Recalculations

Specifically, has there been any indication whether they will end-of-life them, or start supporting them via Lightning setup?

Answer (score 2):

salesforce.com will definitely not be setting an end-of-life for these features any time soon; there's too many clients that use them. However, they also haven't announced that these features will come out in the UI in the next two releases, either. Unfortunately, we may not know more about these features until at least 2019. In the interim, feel free to use them if you need to, because they're not going anyway any time in the foreseeable future.